# how can I move data from screen to another in textual framework

Tags: python, rich, textual, python-textual

basically my app is rss feeder, the first step is to put all feeds in one screen and I called it `ArticlesGrid` with `publish date`, `provider name` and `title`, I finished the focus thing and my app is working fine, but it needs to be useful so, I tried to show other data if user press `enter` like the `link` and `full content`, but I can't find anything that I can use like routing or navigating, there is `push_screen` method but it is push a new screen without any data from previous screen, is there anything can push data for specific cell in grid? like `for this card push title`, this is my code and I don't know what to do and cant find any code from community.

```py
class ArticlesGrid(Grid):
    def compose(self) -> ComposeResult:
        for article_info in self.content:
            article = ArticleCard(article_info.get("title"))
            article.border_title = article_info.get("provider")
            article.border_subtitle = article_info.get("pub_date")
            yield article

    def handle_key(self, event: events.Key) -> bool:
        if event.key == "enter":
            focused_card = self.focus()
            if focused_card is not None:
                self.app.push_screen(...)

    @property
    def content(self):
        feeds = get_content()
        data = []
        for provider, feed in feeds.items():
            for article in feed:
                data.append(
                    {
                        "provider": provider,
                        "title": article.title,
                        "description": article.description,
                        "content": article.content,
                        "link": article.link,
                        "pub_date": article.pub_date,
                        "author": article.author,
                        "authors": article.authors,
                        "tags": article.tags,
                    }
                )
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a custom screen, you can override the constructor to pass in any arguments you may need. Something like the following:

```py
class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, greet:str):
        self.greet = greet
        super().__init__()

    def compose(self):
        yield Label(f"Hello {self.greet}")
```

When you push the screen you can add your arguments:

```py
self.push_screen(MyScreen("Will"))
```